# Symfony 3 Doctrine Associations & Forms

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

Thanks in advance. I'm beginning some Symfony work and got stuck (maybe in my head).

Following this link on doctrine associations:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html

I am confused as how this could be implemented with a form.

```
$builder
        ->add('proName', TextType::class, array (
                'label' => 'Product Name',
                'attr' => array ('class'=>'testforidontypes')
            ))
        ->add('proPrice', MoneyType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Product Price',
                'currency' => "USD")
            )
        ->add('category', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices' => array (
                        'Uncategorized'=>' ',
                        'Cables'=>'Cables',
                        'Television'=>'Television',
                        'Desktop'=>'Desktop',
                        'Laptop'=>'Laptop',
                        'Smart Phone'=>'Smart Phone',                           
                        'Accessories'=>'Accessories',                       
                    ),
                )
            )
        ->add('proDescription', TextareaType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Product Description',
            ))
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array(
            'label'=>'Add New Product')
            )
```

The category type is what I am running circles around. All fields are mapped to the correct entity and everything is good with the association.

How to I correctly correspond the two entities through a form? I am a bit lost maybe because I am asking the wrong questions...

Thanks again...

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking.  Try some things out, and when you get stuck on very specific try modifying your question with those specifics.

Comment: Okay. basically...getting the selection from the dropdown selection (cables, desktop, etc;) from the form to convert in the controller into the category...like I said I am a bit lost...

Comment: There is extensive documentation here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html and at the initial link you looked at.  Go through that

Comment: Alrighty...Thanks